# OracleCommand.Parameters - Same Parameter Used Multiple Times

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle, parameters

If I had the below select query being used in an `OracleCommand`, would I need to add the parameter twice for `Col3`?

```
select col_1, col_2 from table_one
  where col_3 = :Col3
union
select col_1, col_2 from table_two
  where col_3 = :Col3;
```

Note `:Col3` used in both sides of the Union

Do I need to add a parameter two times, or can the oracle command reuse the same value?

```
dim cmd As New OracleCommand()
cmd.Parameters.Add(":Col3", "My value")
cmd.Parameters.Add(":Col3", "My value") ' <-- Is this second parameter necessary?'
cmd.BindByName = True
```

I haven't been able to find a solid answer to this yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to supply the parameter once as it has the same parameter name (`:Col3`). The OracleCommand object will automatically supply the same value to both/all instances of the parameter.

If you want different values in your example, one for each union, you would have to use/supply two parameters with different names.

Also, you will need to use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":Col3", "value")` in the above example. Simply using `cmd.Parameters.Add()` expects the parameter name and value type, you will still need to set the value.

Answer (score 2):

No you don't need to supply parameters twice because you are using -

```
cmd.BindByName = True
```